# Fraction of zeros

Tags: fractions

What is the definition of "fraction of zeros"?

Here is [an example of its usage](https://books.google.pt/books?id=h5otEA3YfecC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22fraction%20of%20zeros%22&source=bl&ots=eIy7d8IHnK&sig=51I6rARWYZBmQ5S9GFNCNLdbpOc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC6pHipKHOAhUB7hoKHfhHCW0Q6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22fraction%20of%20zeros%22&f=false).

Sorry for such a simple question, but I have searched quite a bit now and have not been able to find a definition for this.

Comment: Without too much further context, I would interpret the phrase as "fraction of [outcomes which are] zeros".

Comment: In context, it'd be the same thing of say "percentage of cats" i.e. what percentage of a sample are cats.  In this case instead of taking a sample of animals you are taking a sample of numerical results, some fraction of which are zero.  I have to admit "fraction of zero" is a very poor choice of words as it sounds as though it could mean an arithmetic term the reader is unfamiliar with instead of its prosaic meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fraction of zeros is the percentage amount of statistical data which is zero. It is relevant in statistical models where a *significant* amount of objects has zero value. See *[zero inflated models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model)* for some more information or *[this blog](http://statisticalhorizons.com/zero-inflated-models)* for discussing their relevance.

You may also search for the string *zero* in your referred book. You will find there some text entries  about  inflated models.